# How to parse google weather xml data in android

Tags: android, xml

Ive been trying to get this to work for like three hours now. These are the two pieces of code i tried and the link to the xml file. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong or how to easily do this? I just want to get the current temp stored as "temp_f" in the "current_conditions" element. If there is a better way of doing this than either of my attempts i would love to know. Thank you so much!

Here is a link to the xml file i download from the net:
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=10598

This is the code i use to get the xml data from the web:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        // HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
        try {
            HttpResponse rsp = client.execute(get);
            String xmltemp = EntityUtils.toString(rsp.getEntity());
            System.out.println(xmltemp);
```

Then i tried both of these to try to parse the xml but neither worked.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory1 = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        factory1.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmltemp));
        Document doc = factory1.newDocumentBuilder().parse(source);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element "
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        Log.d("OUTPUT","Root element "
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("weather");

        for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

            Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

            if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;

                NodeList fstNmElmntLst = ((Document) fstElmnt)
                        .getElementsByTagName("module_id");
                Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
                NodeList fstNm = ((Node) fstNmElmnt).getChildNodes();
                System.out.println(((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                newal.add("" + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                Log.d("OUTPUT","" + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
            }

        }
```

And this:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory1 = DocumentBuilderFactory
             .newInstance(); factory1.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
             InputSource source = new InputSource(new
             StringReader(xmltemp)); Document doc =
             factory1.newDocumentBuilder().parse(source);

             XPathFactory factory11 = XPathFactory.newInstance(); XPath xpath1
             = factory11.newXPath(); XPathExpression expr1 = xpath1 .compile(
             "//forecast_information[postal_code='10598']/forecast_date/text()"
              ); Object result = expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

              NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result; for (int i = 0; i <
              nodes.getLength(); i++) {
              System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
              Log.d("1010101010101",nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); }
```

EDIT:
So this is the code im trying to use now but every time i run it i get this error in logcat:

```
09-15 20:26:47.359: DEBUG/ErOr(17663): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl
```

This is the code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory1.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
            InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmltemp));
            Document doc = factory1.newDocumentBuilder().parse(source);

            String newstring = "" + ((DocumentBuilderFactory) ((Document) doc.getDocumentElement().
               getElementsByTagName("current_conditions").item(0)).
               getElementsByTagName("temp_f").item(0)).
               getAttribute("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to understand is that the "module_id" is not an element, it's an attribute.  So you can't retrieve its value with  getElementsByTagName("module_id").  Also fstElmnt will never be a Document - it's an Element, as you've determined with getNodeType().  To get module_id, you should try: fstElement.getAttribute("module_id").

But to return to your main question: to get the value of the temperature, try this:

```
doc.getDocumentElement().
   getElementsByTagName("current_conditions").item(0).
   getElementsByTagName("temp_f").item(0).
   getAttribute("data");
```

I think that's it - untested!

Comment: I tried that but getChildNodes says "The method getChildNodes() in the type Node is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: You're absolutely right - face palm - the DOM API really is terrible - I've become used to using JDOM instead, which is much saner.  I'll edit the answer...

Comment: Thanks... maybe this is a dumb question but how do i get that data into a string so i can test to see if it actually works?

Comment: The expression I put in the answer returns a String.  I think that's what you need, right?

Comment: Yeah im sorry... I keep getting this error in logcat "09-15 20:26:47.359: DEBUG/ErOr(17663): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl
"